# Bootstrap 4 images thumbnail classes

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I got a HTML code in the following using bootstrap 3.3.7, 
using thumbnail class the images can be resized and fit into the grid perfectly.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Project</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Pictures of Coffee</h2>
  <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt=""></div> 
  </div>
</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

However, the thumbnail class doesn't seem to be exist in bootstrap 4.0
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/
To simulate the issue you can try to replace the html link rel with the following

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
 crossorigin="anonymous">
```

You can see the images will be out of places and I would like to know what is the similar class to achieve the same result in 4.0. Or i have to resort to bootstrap 3.3.7 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [docs v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#image-thumbnails), you are looking for `img-thumbnail` (which should be used in `img` tag instead of `col-*-*` as you have)

**Notes:**

- In v4 `col-xs` was replaced by `col-`
- I've added `img-fluid` utility class in order to make images responsive

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <h2>Pictures of Coffee</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 "><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 "><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 "><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 "><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 "><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 "><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply, i have only used img-thumbnail class previously, and that's why i couldn't get it working. This is the answer that i am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In Bootstrap 4 you can do the following.

For columns `col-xs-` doesn't exist anymore, replace with `col-`. The default is `xs`.

For the thumbnail, you can use the `img-thumbnail` class on the `img` element instead of on the `div` element.

Additionally, to achieve 0 padding on each column and row, you can override Bootstrap's padding by adding a custom style rule.

```
    .row > .col-lg-4,
       .col-6 {
               padding: 0;
       }
```

The resulting Bootstrap 4 file would be the following:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Project</title>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            .row>.col-lg-4,
            .col-6 {
                padding: 0;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Pictures of Coffee</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! it can work as well, but i will mark dippas's answer as it is much cleaner. No override is needed.

Comment: You are not achieving the same look with dippa's. The original using bootstrap 3 has no spacing between the images. That is why I added the padding of 0.